# How do you set a scrollView to fill the remainder of the screen with a static navbar at the bottom?

Tags: java, android

My goal is to have 2 static buttons at the bottom of the screen at all times "Back" and "Add Event." I have a scrollView that holds a list of items, currently that view just shows one row instead of all that rows that can fit on the screen. The reason I used a scrollView was because I wanted the user to be able to scroll through more options if it exceeds the screen length. Is there a way to expand the Scrollview/Listview without using DP(since that doesn't always correlate well with different screen sizes).

[image]

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/user_event_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="left|bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:text="back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:text="add Event" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ListView inside scroll view?

Answer (score 1):

Do not nest ListView inside ScrollView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="back"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="add Event"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/user_event_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/user_event_table"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ListView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/back_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                android:text="back" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                android:text="add Event" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Actually, you need not put listview in scrollview. Listview will contain scroll by default